# iTextSharp table width 100% of page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, width

I'm trying to add a table to a document using iTextSharp. Here is an example:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER,72, 72, 72, 72);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));

document.Open();
Table table = new Table ( 2, 1 );
table.Width = document.RightMargin - document.LeftMargin;

// Cell placeholder
Cell cell = new Cell ( new Paragraph ( "Some Text" ) );
table.AddCell ( cell );
cell = new Cell ( new Paragraph ( "More Text" ) );
table.AddCell ( cell );
document.Add ( table );
document.Close ( );
```

I'm setting the width of the table so that it should extend the margin of the page. But when the pdf is created the table only takes about 80% of the space between the margin's. Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In iTextSharp latest version (5.0.4) the `PdfPTable` has a `WidthPercentage` property.

To set a static value the property is `TotalWidth`.

Comment: [5.5.9]
TotalWidth is not a static value - it's just object property.

Answer (score 36):

Figured it out. Apparently `table.Width` is a percent and not the width in pixels. So using:

```
table.Width = 100;
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: I had no option for just width so I used table.WidthPercentage = 100f;

Answer (score 6):

Users can also set table width by Percentage.

```
t.WidthPercentage = 100f;
```

Answer (score 4):

The WidthPercentage property is no longer available in iText7. Use the following instead

```cs
table.SetWidth(new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java `table.setWidthPercentage(100);`
Works in 5.5.8 version

Comment: The question and the other answers focus on itext for .Net in c# syntax. You use itext for java in java syntax. That's all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In c# for itext7

```
Table details = new Table(4, false).UseAllAvailableWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
```

will work